# Convergence of $g _ { n } ( x ) = \int _ { 0 } ^ { x }f_n(t)dt $

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

Let $f _ { n }: \mathbb { R } \rightarrow \mathbb { R }$ be
a sequence of $\mathcal C'$ functions, converges to $f$ uniformely,
then we have $\int _ { 0 } ^ { x }f_n(t)dt$ converges to $\int_{0} ^ { x } f ( t ) d t ~~\forall x \in \mathbb { R}$, Then what about the convergence of
$g _ { n } ( x ) = \int _ { 0 } ^ { x }f_n(t)dt $ to $g ( x ) = \int _ { 0 } ^ { x } f ( t ) d t.$
is it uniform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not. Consider $f(x)= c$ for some constant $c\in\mathbb R$ and $f_n(x)=c+1/n$.

Then $g_n(x)-g(x)=\frac xn$ which doesn't converge to $0$ uniformly on $\mathbb R$.

---

EDIT: Additional question: What happens on a closed interval $[0,a]$?

Answer: Then we have for all $x\in[0,a]$, $$|g_n(x)-g(x)|\le\int_0^x |f(x)-f_n(x)|\,\mathrm dx\le x\cdot M_n \le a\cdot M_n$$

where the $M_n$ can be chosen to go to $0$ since the $f_n$ converge uniformly to $f$. So the $g_n$ converge uniformly to $g$ in this case.

Comment: Janisch, I like your example. It's so cool. Can you please tell me how can someone find/create good counterexamples in Analysis? Thanks so much.

Comment: What about the convergence in a closed interval?

Comment: @MMM The intuition here is that if we define $f_n$ as $f+a_n$, where $f$ is any "nice" (for example continuously differentiable function) and $a_n\to 0$, $a_n\neq 0$, then we have that $f_n$ only differs $a_n$ from $f$ but $g_n$ differs $x\cdot a_n$ from $g$.

Comment: @RIYASUDHEENT.K See what I have added

Comment: For the closed interval case, the answer is yes.